# remove the space between repeated background css

Tags: css, background

I have a repeated background in a long page and I want to know how remove the space between the repeated background.

```
body {
  background-image:url('bg.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: Put padding:0; margin:0 in your css and ensure there is no white space on your image

Comment: I tried but the background disappeared.

Comment: your code should work. check the image corners.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any space in between a repeated background.  Double check your image, you may need to crop out a border or some whitespace.

Also, if you pasted Darren's code into your CSS above the background-image:url('bg.jpg'); part your background would disappear because his margin:0 is missing a semi-colon.

Comment: You could do a google reverse image search to find a higher quality version of the background.  You should probably have created a link to your bg.jpg image so that people can determine what's wrong.

Comment: there was no space when I was using the code in local server but when I upload it it in host site the space appears.

Comment: What hosting service are you using?  Disable any option they may have that tries to resize your image.

Comment: this one:  byethost.com

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the image. CorelDRAW for example adds a transparent border when you export the image. You need in this case to set the width or height to the same in the draw in transformation on the export window. Sorry for grammar errors, I'm not American...